# How to tell bootstrap to keep right column?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a bookstrap website with a col-lg-7 / col-lg-5 grid layout:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    ...
</div>
<div class="row" style="padding: 0 20px 0 0">
    <div class="col-lg-7">
        <div style="padding: 5px 0 0 30px">
            222
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <div class="panel" style="border: none !important;margin: 0 0 0 0">
            ...
        </div>      
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            ....
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It looks fine when the browser is full screen, showing the `col-lg-5` nicely on the right side as a right-hand column, but as soon as I reduce the screen to even about 80% of the screen, the `col-lg-5` column jumps down under the `col-lg-7` column.

**How can I tell bootstrap that I want it to keep a 7/5 ratio no matter how wide the screen is, so that the page always has a right-hand column?**

Comment: You do know what `lg` mean? Define rules for `lg,md,sm,xs`.

Comment: If you always want 7/5, then I think you can just use `col-xs-7` and `col-xs-5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark is correct.  Change your col-lg to col-xs and the columns will adjust in size according to screen size as opposed to changing their positions on the screen.

Comment: Yes, that solves the problem, but when the browser gets to be about 40% of the screen, text starts moving outside of the margins of the right panel. Is there a way to tell the row to stop resizing at a certain width, this doesn't have any affect: `<div class="row" style="padding: 0 20px 0 0;min-width: 500px">`.

Comment: Could you create a fiddle with your html and css to show your problem?

Comment: so basically the question is: doesnt want the columns to stack (always maintain the 7/5 ratio) - but also doesnt want the columns to be fluid - ie. shrink as the browser viewport gets smaller - you may actually be wanting a twitter bootstrap non-responsive site - documentation here <http://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/>

Comment: ok, creating the fiddle helped me solve the problem, it works now, very nice, thanks, http://jsfiddle.net/vdcL3due

Comment: Awesome! Glad you got it figured out :)